# JQueryMobile Cordova Application not looking good

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm just getting started with Cordova+JQM, this is my first app but the application is not looking like an application rather a plain page with no sense of borders.
Here's my meta tag:

`<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no,width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />`

And the stylesheets and scripts included:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Jquery.js"></script>
```

Code for the page:

```
        <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Testing</h1>
</div><!-- /header -->
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
    <a href="#" onclick="playAudio(url);" class="ui-btn ui-shadow">Play</a>
    <button onclick="stopAudio()" class="ui-btn ui-shadow">Stop</button>
</div>

<div  data-role="footer">
    <h4>The End</h4>
</div><!-- /footer -->
    </div>
```

Here's what it looks like:
[image: Screenshot]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Load jquery before jquery mobile.

Comment: It helped, I completely overlooked that my bad.